# Get element from json array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have a simple Json String

```
[
   {
      "assetName":"LCT",
      "assetValue":"",
      "typeValueInput":"select",
      "valueInputSelect":null,
      "required":true,
      "valueInput":"{\"data\":[{\"name\":\"name1\",\"id\":\"12\"},{\"name\":\"name2\",\"id\":\"13\"},{\"name\":\"name3\",\"id\":\"14\"}]}"
   }
]
```

I want get field Name in Data in ValueInput by Javascript.

Please help me!

Comment: You can use `JSON.parse` to convert json to object.

Comment: Why does this have seven upvotes? It does not show **any** effort made by the OP. What did they try? What did not work? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 5):

You need to loop through the array and then parse the stringified JSON so that you can access the `data` array. Then simply loop that `data` array to get the value of each `name` property.

```js
var arr = [{
  "assetName": "LCT",
  "assetValue": "",
  "typeValueInput": "select",
  "valueInputSelect": null,
  "required": true,
  "valueInput": "{\"data\":[{\"name\":\"name1\",\"id\":\"12\"},{\"name\":\"name2\",\"id\":\"13\"},{\"name\":\"name3\",\"id\":\"14\"}]}"
}];

arr.forEach((arrObj) => {
  var jsonData = JSON.parse(arrObj.valueInput);
  jsonData.data.forEach(({name}) => console.log(name));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `JSON.parse`

```js
var jsonArray = [
  {
    assetName: 'LCT',
    assetValue: '',
    typeValueInput: 'select',
    valueInputSelect: null,
    required: true,
    valueInput:
      '{"data":[{"name":"name1","id":"12"},{"name":"name2","id":"13"},{"name":"name3","id":"14"}]}'
  }
];

let name = jsonArray[0].valueInput;
name = JSON.parse(name);
name.data.forEach(value => {
  console.log(value.name, value.id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `JSON.parse`, and use `map`:

```js
const data = [{
  "assetName": "LCT",
  "assetValue": "",
  "typeValueInput": "select",
  "valueInputSelect": null,
  "required": true,
  "valueInput": "{\"data\":[{\"name\":\"name1\",\"id\":\"12\"},{\"name\":\"name2\",\"id\":\"13\"},{\"name\":\"name3\",\"id\":\"14\"}]}"
}]
const names = JSON.parse(data[0].valueInput).data.map(({ name }) => name);
console.log(names);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```
JSON.parse(o[0].valueInput).data[0].name
```

```js
var o = [
   {
      "assetName":"LCT",
      "assetValue":"",
      "typeValueInput":"select",
      "valueInputSelect":null,
      "required":true,
      "valueInput":"{\"data\":[{\"name\":\"name1\",\"id\":\"12\"},{\"name\":\"name2\",\"id\":\"13\"},{\"name\":\"name3\",\"id\":\"14\"}]}"
   }
]

console.log(JSON.parse(o[0].valueInput).data[0].name);

// To get all, use a loop

var arrO = JSON.parse(o[0].valueInput).data;

arrO.forEach((obj) => console.log(obj.name))
```

Comment: @Deepakgupta `data[0]` is not a string, the array is parsed before. See the live demo before post a comment

Comment: the input value is a string, not an object, and the string is not correctly stringified.

Comment: @AZ_ The input value is not a string. Jack make some bad edit

Comment: it says *I have a simple Json String* not sure maybe.

Comment: @AZ_ Yes he have a json string into the key `valueInput`

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```js
const arr = [{"assetName": "LCT","assetValue": "","typeValueInput": "select","valueInputSelect": null,"required": true,"valueInput": "{\"data\":[{\"name\":\"name1\",\"id\":\"12\"},{\"name\":\"name2\",\"id\":\"13\"},{\"name\":\"name3\",\"id\":\"14\"}]}"}];

arr.forEach(o => JSON.parse(o.valueInput).data.forEach(({id, name}) => console.log(id, name)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `array` variable and the callback function of `JSON.parse` to get the name `key` & `val`

```js
let dt = [{
  "assetName": "LCT",
  "assetValue": "",
  "typeValueInput": "select",
  "valueInputSelect": null,
  "required": true,
  "valueInput": "{\"data\":[{\"name\":\"name1\",\"id\":\"12\"},{\"name\":\"name2\",\"id\":\"13\"},{\"name\":\"name3\",\"id\":\"14\"}]}"
}];
let nameArray = [];

let dlt = JSON.parse(dt[0].valueInput, function(key, val) {
  if (key === 'name') {
    nameArray.push(val);
  }
})

console.log(nameArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it.

```
let originalData = [
   {
      "assetName":"LCT",
      "assetValue":"",
      "typeValueInput":"select",
      "valueInputSelect":null,
      "required":true,
      "valueInput":"{\"data\":[{\"name\":\"name1\",\"id\":\"12\"},{\"name\":\"name2\",\"id\":\"13\"},{\"name\":\"name3\",\"id\":\"14\"}]}"
   }
];

let valueInput = JSON.parse(originalData[0].valueInput);

let data = valueInput.data;

console.log(data);

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    console.log(data[i].name);
}
```

See jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3s1na4eL/3/

Let me know if there are any questions.